# Regular Expression for a Set of Strings of Even Length

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

Can the language for the set of even strings be represented by

```
L={ε,aa,ab,ba,bb.....}
```

Isnt Epsilon Odd?

Comment: $\varepsilon$ represents the empty string so it has length $0$ which is even.

Comment: @JohnDouma Okay.Got it now,can you add that as an answer please.

Comment: I appreciate that. Thank you.